# Useful alternative uses for yield beyond being an anonymous method?

Tags: ruby, yield, proc

Example:

```
a = Proc.new do
  b = 'hey'
end

def a_method
  yield
end

a_method(&a) #=> 'hey'
```

I understand that `yield` (or `block.call`) can be used as a simple co-routine, but I was wondering, are there any more (practical) uses for it beyond simply getting the return value from it? Can we get some of the local variables from the proc into the main method etc.?

Comment: Are you familiar with `instance_eval`? Depending on your use case, it could work.

Comment: Can you give an example of a simple use case for this? It's easy to do what you're asking, but the best way to do it depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you mean something more than `a = Proc.new {b = 'hey'}; def a_method; yield; end; puts a_method(&a) #=> "hey"`? `"hey"` is returned by the proc, so `b` doesn't add anything.

Comment: Uh Cary, yes, something like this. I'm trying to understand useful ways to use yield beyond calling the block as a simple anonymous method.

Comment: Cary's code sample works because the return value of the block is "hey", not because of the scoping of the variables. If that coincidence solves your issue, though, then all's well that ends well.

Comment: I understand why Cary's example works, as I mentioned in my previous comment, the whole purpose behind this question is trying to understand useful ways to use yield beyond being an anonymous method.

Comment: I was responding to your pre-edit comment that said "I'll delete this question." As for `yield`, it is only and exactly syntactic sugar for `block.call` that allows you to omit `(&block)` as a named argument in the method definition.

Comment: I've edited my question appropriately so your answer is still relevant and outlines one approach to using yield beyond a simple co-routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not picky about the return value of the block, you can do it using `binding`.

```
a = Proc.new do
  b = 'hey'
  binding
end

def a_method
  new_binding = yield

  p new_binding.eval("b")
end

a_method(&a)
# => "hey"
```

If you're using a version of Ruby >= 2.1.0, you can avoid the ickiness of `eval` by using `local_variable_get` instead:

```
p new_binding.local_variable_get(:b)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of uses for Procs. For example, you can use it to give instructions to an object. I made a bubble sort using a proc that tells it how to sort. Here it is monkey patched in the array class:

```
class Array
  def bubble_sort(&prc)
    self.dup.bubble_sort!(&prc)
  end

  def bubble_sort!(&prc)
    return self if count <= 1
    prc = Proc.new { |x, y| x <=> y } unless prc.class == Proc
    (0...self.count).each do |x|
      ((x + 1)...self.count).each do |y|
        self[x], self[y] = self[y], self[x] if prc.call(self[x], self[y]) == 1
      end
    end
    self
  end
end
```